# Symfony3 one-to-many relationship __toString error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, associations, entities

I am following the [symfony documentation for associations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html) and I created Product and Category entities.

In my Product entity I have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $category;
```

In my Category entity I have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
 */
private $products;
```

Here is how the generated tables look like:

```
mysql> show create table product \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: product
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `details` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT '(DC2Type:json_array)',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_D34A04AD12469DE2` (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D34A04AD12469DE2` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table category \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: category
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I also installed the EasyAdmin bundle. Now, I go to EasyAdmin and open 'Category' table and insert a row. Then I go to 'Product' table and when I click on 'Add Product' button, I get the error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Category could not be converted to string
```

It is possible to fix the problem by adding a magic method __toString which returns $this->name into Category entity.

Question:

1- Am I doing something wrong? Why do I need to add __toString method to Category entity?

2- If this is normal, why this is not mentioned in the symfony manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No doubt about it this the normal behaviour. I've done it many times with EasyAdminbundle.

You have to implement the `__toString()` method.

> Fields that represent an association with another entity are displayed
>   as  lists. For that reason, you must define the __toString()
>   PHP method in any entity which is used in a Doctrine relation.
>   Otherwise you'll see an error message because the backend cannot
>   represent the related object as a string.

It is in the doc here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html

Comment: Yes, I didn't see that. But now I am thinking the better way for me is to disable autocomplete for this field. Because the number of records in the relationship may be eventually overwhelming perhaps.

Comment: If have already worked for projects where the <select> list contained more  than 3000 <option> children and I didn't notice any notable performance decrease .

Comment: I will work with some felds which will have over 100million entries... But I will let it be until it becomes a bottleneck...One problem at a time :)

Comment: then you could force EasyAdminBundle to use only ajax autocomplete with type: 'easyadmin_autocomplete'. This type is useful to improve the backend performance when a field is related to an entity with lots of database records see doc here https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) Add a __toString() method to your entity on the "many" side of the relationship that returns a string that identifies the entity.

2) Be sure that the __toString() method returns a string in every circumstance, even if the entity is completely empty. Often you have to initialize the property that __toString() returns as an empty string.

example:

```
private $name = ''; // initialize $name as an empty string

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name; // which is a string in any circumstance
}
```